# How can I check for system updates without being forced to update my system?

Tags: updates, application-autoupdate, android-12, google-pixel-6

I use a Google Pixel 6 with Android 12.

How can I check for system updates without being forced to update my system?

When I tapped on  check for updates in the settings, it then forces me to update my system:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you check for an update if you don't want to install it? Google usually pushes security updates on 5th of every month, so you don't have to check. There are also bulletins describing the recent update and it's (security) changes.

Comment: @Robert thanks, all programs I know except chrome allow  users to check for updates without installing them.  That's very impolite to install anything without the consent of the user.